# MSP430G2553 UART Baudrate and Control Registers. Can I use word access?

Tags: uart, msp430

Is it possible to program MSP430G2553 UART registers with word access or are the internal peripherals only byte wide and therefore only byte accessible?

(I know that MCTL is only byte wide on this device.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2xx family User's Guide says in section 1.4.3:

> The address space from 010h to 0FFh is reserved for 8-bit peripheral modules. These modules should be accessed with byte instructions. Read access of byte modules using word instructions results in unpredictable data in the high byte. If word data is written to a byte module only the low byte is written into the peripheral register, ignoring the high byte.

Comment: I would _really_ like to know about the UCA0BR1 UCA0BR0 vs UCA0BR and UCA0CTL1 UCA0CTL0 vs UCA0CTL registers.  RXBUF and TXBUF are 8-bit by definition.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the data that is transferred, not the registers themselves.